# messageCreate event no longer firing after adding the interactionCreate event

Tags: discord, discord.js

To start: Yes I have intents setup. I have the "message content" intent enabled in the developer portal.

Recently I decided to setup slash commands for my bot. (That is all working fine, not the purpose of this question). Now however, I find that my "messageCreate" event is not firing at all. I've done some basic testing, including removing the "interactionCreate" event, and it still is non-functional. The only fix I've found is completely reverting to the previous version on my source control.

I haven't been able to find any solutions from the discord.js Discord so I decided to come here in the hopes someone can help. Thanks for your time! Client constructor and event code attached below.

Client:

```
const myIntents = new Intents(
    Intents.FLAGS.GUILDS,
    Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_MESSAGES,
    Intents.FLAGS.DIRECT_MESSAGES,
    Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_MESSAGE_REACTIONS,
    Intents.FLAGS.DIRECT_MESSAGE_REACTIONS
);

const client = new Client({ intents: myIntents, partials: ["CHANNEL"] });
```

Events:

```
client.once('ready', () => {
    // Works fine
});

client.on('interactionCreate', async interaction => {
    // Works fine
});

client.on('messageCreate', async message => {
    console.log('DEBUG') // Never triggers
    // Other stuff
});

client.on("error", (e) => console.error(e));
client.on("warn", (e) => console.warn(e));
process.on('unhandledRejection', (e) => console.error(e));

console.log("client") // All events, including messageCreate, are visible in the resulting output

client.login(config.token);
```

Comment: Can you share your discord.js version

Comment: @SuleymanCelik discord.js@13.3.1

Comment: I tried and it's working but I have different intents. Here's my code if you want to check; https://gist.github.com/SuleymanEfe/5d69cb404d061d873450d83c07f20d97

Answer (score 0):

I think you need the "MESSAGE" partial.
You can try and replace

```js
const client = new Client({ intents: myIntents, partials: ["CHANNEL"] });
```

To

```js
const client = new Client({ intents: myIntents, partials: ["CHANNEL", "MESSAGE"] });
```

Moreover, I had the same issue but I was very dumb because I didn't realize that my bot didn't have "READ MESSAGES" and "SEND MESSAGES" permissions in that channel, so that might be the issue.

Comment: Oh hi PGamer! We already talked in the Discord.js chat remember? I just added the "MESSAGE" partial to my bot, and that didn't fix the issue. It still cannot pick up messages sent in any channel (And it has admin permission inside my testing server).

Comment: Oh wait, that was you haha. I was wondering where else I saw a similar message lol. Also, I cannot understand what else is possibly causing this issue, sorry.